# How to get Most recently created Opp in a list from a map

Tags: apex, visualforce

Below is my code, `accIds`have multiple account IDs, so I have multiple case of multiple Accounts

```
lstCase =[SELECT Id,Accountid,CreatedDate FROM Case where AccountId IN: accIds ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];

        for(Case pc: lstCase){
            system.debug('pc---'+pc);
                if(accountCaseMap.containsKey(pc.Accountid)){
                    accountCaseMap.get(pc.Accountid).add(pc);
                }else{
                    accountCaseMap.put(pc.Accountid, new List<Case>{pc});
                }
        }
```

Now I have `accountCaseMap` map with List of Cases associated with their AccountID.
How I can get a list of most recently created Cases in a map associated with their Account.

[AccountId, CreatedDate check for one Case out of all]

Answer (score 1):

Simpler approach would be to create the `Map` with single latest `Opportunity`

```
Map<Id, Opportunity> accountOppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
for(Account acc : [SELECT id,Name, (SELECT id from Opportunities ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1)  FROM Account]){
    if(!acc.Opportunities.isEmpty())
        accountOppMap.put(acc.Id,acc.Opportunities);
    else 
        accountOppMap.put(acc.Id,new Opportunity());
}
system.debug(accountOppMap);
```

Comment: Can you please look into the code snippet again

Comment: Other than that you changed your question from Opportunity to Case, how does this answer not solve your problem? If you have a different need, would you please edit your question to be clearer?

Comment: @sfdcrowdy You just need to replace Opportunity with Case in the solution provided, that should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

A simple SOQL query can let us know the most recent Opportunity created:-

```
for(Account acc : [Select id,Name (SELECT id, Name from Opportunity ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 10) FROM Account]){
    accountOppMap.put(acc.Id,acc.Opportunities);
}
```

Child relationship name of Opportunity is `Opportunities`. Above snipped will return most recent 10 opportunity associated with the Account.